# Are there any list types that can be bound to a datagridview and support sorting/searching without needing custom classes or code to make them work?

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a datagridview that has a list of objects built from a DB bound to it.  The default sorting of a datagridview wasnt working and I find out that its because a list doesn't support sorting.
I really don't care what kind of collection I use as long as I can 
A: sort the list by column on header click
B: search the list by a specific column
C: Get the object back when the user selects a row.

I have C working fine with a list but A and B wont work.

```
    private BindingSource rollingStockSource = new BindingSource();
    dgvInventoryList.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
    List<RollingStock> rollingStockList =RollingStockDAO.GetRollingStocks();
    rollingStockSource.DataSource = rollingStockList;
    dgvInventoryList.DataSource = rollingStockSource;
```

This is how im setting up my datagridview now.  Im setting my columns and tying them to object attributes in the form editor rather than in the code with the DataPropertyName field.

Is there no list that comes with sorting/searching by default?

Comment: I'd recommend using a `DataTable`, if you can. Then you can sort by clicking the column header

Comment: If the data comes from a DB then a DataTable is certainly the way to go - not extra effort at all.  But a `List<T>` does support sorting.

Comment: All the reading I did said a basic List<T> doesnt support sorting.  If it does then why won't the default sorting of my datagridview work for me?